# public static property won't show in intellisense

Tags: c#, static

I'm slowly learning C# and bit confused about the code. I have here a simplified version of my class for the database connection settings

```
public class DatabaseSettings
{
    private static string connectionString = string.Empty;

    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get 
        {
            return connectionString;
        }
        private set
        {
            connectionString = value;
        }
    }

    public bool TestConnection()
    {
        bool _returnVal = false;
        string _connectionString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Persist Security Info=False", databaseLocation);

        using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                connectionString = _connectionString; // sets the value of the connection string here
                _returnVal = true;
            }
            catch (SqlCeException e)
            {
                // other codes here
                _returnVal = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return _returnVal;
    }

    // other methods here
}
```

now on my `Main Class`, I am confused what is happening here. When i tried this code:

```
string _databaseLocation = "database path";
DatabaseSettings _dbaseSetting = new DatabaseSettings(_databaseLocation, true);
_dbaseSetting.TestConnection();
string newConnectionString = _dbaseSetting.ConnectionString;
//                                        ^ i got an error here
// Member 'SQLCE_Sample.ClassList.DatabaseSettings.ConnectionString.get' 
// cannot be accessed with an instance reference; 
// qualify it with a type name instead
```

this one below works without an error but the problem is I got an empty string:

```
string _databaseLocation = "database path";
DatabaseSettings _dbaseSetting = new DatabaseSettings(_databaseLocation, true);
string newConnectionString = DatabaseSettings.ConnectionString;
```

What I really want is I need to create a class that has a `public method` which *tests the connection from the application to the database*. Inside that method contains a syntax that *sets the value of the connection string*. Then I need also a `property` that *retrieves the value of the connection string* without instantiating the class (*that's why i added the `static` keyword*). How can I possibly to this?

Comment: What is `databaseLocation`, and where does it come from?  If it is supplied by the caller, then you can just convert your connection string property to a get method with `databaseLocation` as a parameter.  Otherwise you will need to do some refactoring to generate your connection string from more complicated logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want to access (statically) the value of a property that is set by an instance of your class.  So, all you need to do is listen to the compiler error -- access the property as a static reference rather than an instance reference.  Change:

```
string newConnectionString = _dbaseSetting.ConnectionString;
```

To:

```
string newConnectionString = DatabaseSettings.ConnectionString;
```

You'll of course need to make sure that you call `TestConnection` on the instance before you ever try to access the propery statically like this; otherwise `ConnectionString` will be null.

Comment: Notice though that the string itself depends on `databaseLocation`.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk -- yes, that is why I explicitly stipulated that `TestConnection` (an **instance** method) must be invoked before accessing the property statically.

Comment: His problem is that he wants to get the connection string without actually instantiating the class.  I have a suspicion that `databaseLocation` is just a string that he could easily pass to a static `GetConnectionString` method.

Comment: @Michael, you might be right.  But my read on the OP's question is that he *always* invokes `TestConnection` (as an instance method -- perhaps in some initialization section) but wants to be able to freely obtain the connection string without having to bother with an instance.

Comment: That seems true.  In that case the `TestConnection` logic may as well be part of the constructor for `DatabaseSettings` itself, or better yet a static factory method.  That would address his real goal of only setting `ConnectionString` when the connection is valid.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk, I completely agree with that.

Answer (score -2):

Your public static variable and static property have same name. Rename either of them.

Comment: I think he is talking about `connectionString` and `ConnectionString`. Variable names can be the same word, but at least one character must be different case.

Comment: @MatthewRz, right, but they are, of course, different case.  Therefore this answer has no application to C#.